# I might need some help on some statistics homework questions

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I have tried all the problems but the most problems I am not sure how to answer. I will need some help on 11 b., 11 e., and all of 12. for 12 d., I got -57.9 but I am not sure how to interpret.

11 b. I said y=202.53+1.4gx 11 c. I said "around 47% of the dots are around the regression line. 11 d. I said "the value of correlation between calories and sodium is moderate. 11 e. I said "the prediction is not reliable.

12 a. I said "No because there is a leftover curved pattern. 12 b. I said "It means when using the lease square regression line with x to predict y will typically be off by about 23. 12 c. I said "-1.993, for every lunch, it will be decreased by -1.993 12 d. I said -57.9.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgMHw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxP1P.png)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve the problems?

Comment: yes, 11 b. I said y=202.53+1.4gx 11 c. I said "around 47% of the dots are around the regression line. 11 d. I said "the value of correlation between calories and sodium is moderate. 11 e. I said "the prediction is not reliable.

12 a. I said "No because there is a leftover curved pattern. 12 b. I said "It means when using the lease square regression line with x to predict y will typically be off by about 23. 12 c. I said "-1.993, for every lunch, it will be decreased by -1.993 12 d. I said -57.9.

Comment: please correct my answers if I have any

Comment: Please choose a title that asks a question. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/321264.

Comment: Please state the problem you are trying to answer. It is OK to post the graph, but you should post the questions directly.